# Zend application models are not autoloading

Tags: php, zend-framework

I started out with models in a module called Api, using the following 
classname/filename conventions:

```
filename:  {project}/application/modules/api/models/Account.php
classname: Api_Model_Account
```

They were happily autoloading through the framework as expected.

I decided that some of these models would be better off, 
organisationally speaking, in the application's models directory as they 
could be used across multiple modules.

I moved them and renamed them:

```
filename:  {project}/application/models/Account.php
classname: Application_Model_Account
```

However, they are not autoloading - PHP throws a `class not found`. I have checked and confirmed my 
configuration (`{project}/application/configs/application.ini`):

```
[production]
appnamespace = "Application"
```

So, the application namespace is 'Application', but the models in the 
application/models directory are not being autoloaded.

Just to make things that little bit crazier - the plugins in application/plugins are being autoloaded.

Testing:

```
<?php

class Application_Model_ExampleTest extends AMH_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase
{
    public function testLoad()
    {
        $moduleModel = new Api_Model_Product();
        $plugin = new Application_Plugin_ModuleErrorControllerSelector();
        $applicationModel = new Application_Model_Example();
    }
}

class AMH_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->bootstrap = new Zend_Application(
            APPLICATION_ENV,
            APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
        );

        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        $this->resetRequest();
        $this->resetResponse();

        parent::tearDown();
    }
}
```

Configuration:

```
[production]
appnamespace = "Application"

bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"

includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"

phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
phpSettings.date.timezone = "Australia/Adelaide"


resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
resources.modules[] = ""

[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

Relevant folder paths:

```
<project name>/
    application/
        models/
            Example.php
        modules/
            api/
                models/
                    Product.php
        plugins/
            ModuleErrorControllerSelector.php
```

Error message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Application_Model_Example' not found in /var/www/accounts.amh.localhost/tests/application/models/ExampleTest.php on line 9
```

This is using Zend Framework 1.10 (package for Ubuntu 10.04)

Comment: So the autoloader is not working only when unit testing?

Comment: That's a pretty old version of ZF. You might need to check when they introduced the `appnamespace` config parameter

Comment: Just checked, was 1.9.2 so you should be fine - http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-7158

Comment: @Phil - yeah, that's one problem with pegging on the LTS release for Ubuntu.

Comment: @Horus Off topic but have a look at Zend Server CE - http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server-Community-Edition/deb_installation.htm

Comment: @Horus What error message(s) are you getting?

Comment: @Phil - just your typical "class not found" error...

Comment: @Horus Try adding the error message to your question anyway. Please include the entire message, including any paths and files mentioned

Comment: @Phil - I've added a whole bunch of information :) probably should have done it to start with, but wasn't entirely sure how to scope the question at first

Comment: actually - this was a bootstrap problem... my `AMH_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase` was an addition I introduced during development since the original problem occured, but not all of my tests were inheriting from it until this morning. I guess the application models were being tested before the first time this bootstrap was run. Sorry and thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method needs to be in all tests to ensure the environment is properly bootstrapped:

```
public function setUp()
{
    $this->bootstrap = new Zend_Application(
        APPLICATION_ENV,
        APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
    );

    parent::setUp();
}
```

Comment: You should move configuring and bootstrapping your Zend_Application instance to a file called bootstrap.php inside your tests/ directory. See the --bootstrap option to the phpunit command-line tool. You can also specify the bootstrap file via command line switch or within the phpunit.xml configuration file. That way you don't have to add it to every single test.

Comment: @jcarouth - I already have a test bootstrap script, but nothing in the documentation for Zend/PHPUnit I've found mentioned the above code - which is why I'm putting it here as my answer. I've created a superclass which inherits from the Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase and all my test cases inherit from that.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why this way its not loading. But another suggestion is you can set the models in include path.

```
set_include_path('.'
    . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'application/models'
    . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the app-level `Bootstrap`, you could configure a [resource loader](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html):

```
protected function _initAutoloader(){
    $resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
        'basePath'      => APPLICATION_PATH,
        'namespace'     => 'Application',
        'resourceTypes' => array(
            'model' => array(
                'namespace' => 'Model',
                'path'      => 'models',
             ),
        ),
    ));
}
```

Comment: They shouldn't have to. ZF automatically adds one of these using the configured `appnamespace` property

Comment: I'll give this a try - but like @Phil said, I shouldn't need this with the version of ZF I'm using.

Comment: @Phil Brown, @HorusKol: Yeah, you're right. Just looked closer at Z_A_B_B. Mysterious indeed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was all about one capital letter.
Model_DbTable_User -> Model_DBTable_User fixed this bug.
Model_DbTable_User was working on my local but not on the server!